# html css how can i shorten tabs

Tags: html, css

I have this problem where the border goes all the way across the screen. How can I make it shorter?

HTML:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li> <a href=page1 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=page2 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=page3 </a> </li>
```

CSS:

```
#tabs { 
    margin: 1em 0 0 0; 
}

#tabs li { 
    display: inline; 
    width: 50px; 
}

#tabs {
    padding: 2px 8px 2px 8px; 
    border: 1px solid #4a7194; 
    margin-left: .5em; text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Though that's not the problem, your anchor tag is wrong and you didn't close your ul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your markup is invalid: you are missing closing angle brackets for your opening anchor tags.

The border goes across the screen because that is the default behaviour for your block element `<ul>`; to take up the width available to it.

There are a few ways you could achieve what you want, one is to [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) your `<ul>` as an inline block element:

```
#tabs {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjmpk84m/)

*Or*

You could [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) your `<ul>` to the left. This will however, remove it from the document flow:

```
#tabs {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    float: left;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjmpk84m/2/)

Unless you don't want it to only span the width of it's contents, but a fixed width:

```
#tabs {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    width: 400px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjmpk84m/3/)